# datatables fnRowCallback: binding click to an event handler

Tags: ajax, jquery, datatables

Using datatables and fnRowCallback.

I am trying to bind click to each row on the 2nd column.
The table is returning the correct anchor in the 2nd column with the correct variables, but when I click on the link, ajax is sending each one as the same userid.

I think i need to use .each().click but every thing I try doesn't work.

Anybody know what im doing wrong.....

```
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="#" id="view_log.php?userid='+ aData[1] +'&acyear='+ aData[2] +'" class="view_log">'+ aData[3] +'</a>').click(function() {
        var url = $('.view_log').attr("id");
        var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
        $("#table_container").hide();
        $(".themenu").hide();
        $("#log").show();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ''+url+'&x='+timestamp,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
              $("#log").html(data);
        }
       });
    });

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried some debugging? Have you checked the aData[1] value?

Comment: yes. the anchor renders fine for each row with the correct id, its the click function that is binding to each row with the id from the first row.

Comment: @Codded, not sure , but how about something like  `var url = this.find('.view_log').attr("id");` or `var url = $this.find('.view_log').attr("id");` or use `closest` instead of `find`

Comment: hi daniel, your suggestions did not work. console.log(url); returns the same id for every row but $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html returns the correct id for each row. strange, could it be something to do with nRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.view_log').attr("id");` will get only the first occurrence.

In this SO page try this in the console:

```
$('.post-tag')   //returns all the tags element
$('.post-tag').attr('href')      //returns only the href value of the first occurrance
```

In the handler, specify the event parameter and then use `$(e.target)` instead.
So `$(e.target).attr('id')` should do the job.

```
... .click(function(e){
  var url = $(e.target).attr('id');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwW8K/)

Comment: var url = $('.view_employee_log');
console.log(url); returned the object with all elements, how can i get the id for each?